# UIActivityController share sheet is blank

Tags: swift3, ios10, uiactivityviewcontroller

I referred to a lot of SO questions regarding this and most seem to be resolved because the OP was trying on simulator and not a real device.

I've been trying on both, but all I see is the image below. I've used the same code with success earlier in a different project, so not sure what is going wrong. All options are missing and More is blank. This is on a real device where other apps' share sheet is working fine.

Here's my code. I'm using Xcode 8.1(beta) and iOS 10.1(beta).

```
    let objectsToShare = ["My text", URL(string: "http://www.google.com") ] as [Any]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll]

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: Any help with this, anyone?

Comment: Make sure everything is unwrapped or is not optional or it will not let it be shared at any place. Answer provided by @marlo below

Answer (score 3):

I just overcome this issue, I made sure that everything added to activityItems are unwrapped/not optional

```
var activityItems: [Any] = []

if let shareURL = URL(string: shareLink) {
    activityItems.append(shareURL)
}

if let shareImage = getShareScreenShot() {
    activityItems.append(shareImage)
}

activityItems.append(shareMessage)

let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code on my physical device without editing and this is the result probably could help you to figure out the issue:

## Result:

[image]

---

## Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBAction func buttonWasTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let objectsToShare = ["My text", URL(string: "http://www.google.com") ] as [Any]

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll]
    
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

---

## iPhone 5S real device, OS version:

[image]

---

## Xcode version:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unwrapping with optional binding and appending the items to the array did not work for me, gave the same results. Here is what worked:

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "test.png", let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") else { return }

let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image,url], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem like so:

```
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
        UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"),
        UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),
    ]
```